# Non-linear regression: confidence intervals and root mean squared error

Tags: confidence-interval, error

I ran a non-linear regression using scipy's curve_fit. I fitted the data using an exponential function $y=a \ e^{bx}$ and calculated the confidence intervals. This is what I get:

[image: Curve fit]

However, when I fit the data using a 3-parameter exponential function $y=a \ e^{bx} + c$, I get much wider confidence intervals:

[image: Curve fit wider confidence intervals]

Why is that?
I then calculated the root mean squared error to see how good is the fit. These are the RMSE I get when I use a 2-parameter exponential function:

1. Blue fit: 0.077
2. Orange fit: 0.097
3. Green fit: 0.091

I know having a low RMSE is good, but aren't these too low? Am I missing something? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**:

I tried a different approach to get confidence intervals: bootstrapping.
This is what I get with a 2-parameter exponential function:
[image]
And for a 3-parameter exponential function:
[image]
I wrote in the below image the values of the function parameters and the 95% confidence intervals for those, for both the "old" method and the bootstrapping one:
[image]
This is what happens for a quadratic function $y=a \ x^2$:
[image]
Here you can see a comparison of the quadratic function's confidence interval obtained with the "old" and with the bootstrapping method:
[image]
In this case, the confidence intervals closely match! Besides doing a visual inspection, I also checked the values of the confidence intervals for the parameter $a$ for both the methods and they are indeed close.
I then assume the difference between the "old" and the new method confidence intervals for the case of a 2-parameter and 3-parameter exponential functions is due to the fact that in the "old" method I was ignoring the covariance between the parameters since to calculate the confidence intervals I made use of the square root of the diagonal entries of the covariance matrix, hence I was not considering the off-diagonal terms.

Comment: The RMSE looks fine to me. Your $y$ values are all between 0 and 1, and the exponential seems to fit the pattern very well, so the vertical distances between the points and the curve is small.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you know why I get those wide confidence intervals when I add a third parameter to the exponential function? Maybe just because it is not the function that bests fit the data? The reason why I added a third parameter is that I know the y-value should be 0 when the x-value is 0. However, since the least square fit only knows what data I input, it makes sense that it doesn't go to exactly 0.

Comment: You might want to think about a robust regression/consider what to do about the outlier point in each data set...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I used bootstrapping to get confidence intervals. The outlier point can still stay there, it looks like the fit isn't disturbed by that point. My purpose is only to find a relation between the two variables (I know there is one, I am just quantifying it) and to justify it statistically.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question - if you ignore the covariances in your confidence interval calculation you'll likely get these bands that are too wide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So even a covariance of e-02 or e-01 is significant?

Comment: Covariance and correlation are not the same.  Your `a` and `c` parameters take low values and have small variances so the covariance of e-02 and e-01 could be very important.  In any case e-01 might be an important correlation (they are always less than 1).

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your design is ill-conditioned for your particular estimates (note that since it's a non-linear least squares fit, the conditioning will depend on your current estimates). If you can get a covariance matrix of your parameter estimates, you'll likely find that at least 2 of a, b and c are strongly correlated. SVD decomposition can also help with this if you can get the Jacobian, small singular values suggest an ill-conditioned problem, and the columns of one of the orthogonal matrices help you find the offending parameters.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I checked the covariance matrices and the off-diagonal terms are mostly in the order of e-03, e-02 and e-01. Being them close to 0, can I still say they are correlated? Anyways, I tried a different approach to get the confidence intervals: bootstrapping. I updated my question with new plots and information. Do you think the confidence intervals now make sense?

Comment: You should check correlation, not covariance. It's the relative scale between the diagonal and off-diagonal elements that matter. And there's no reason bootstrapping should give you better estimates. It looks like the original intervals are prediction intervals which consider all 3 parameters at a time, while your bootstrap curves might be prediction intervals for one variable at a time with the other 2 fixed. You should think about why you want the intervals to begin with, different types are for different things.